# How to rationalise the resonance structures of nitrogen dioxide?

Tags: molecules, covalent-compounds, lewis-structure

The following image depicts resonance in $\ce{NO2}$ molecule:

[image: resonance in NO2]

I don't know if it is obvious or not, but I'm puzzled by this structure. I've read about the [structure of the $\ce{NO2}$ compound](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9448/4945), but it wasn't related.

In the first structure, nitrogen is having a single electron with a positive charge, and oxygen is having a negative charge. So, that means nitrogen has donated a single electron to Oxygen, *without forming a bond*. I know it can be possible, but I couldn't understand how it happens.

Also, I thought that nitrogen donates a lone pair to oxygen, as it can have a *maximum co-valency of 4*. As in the following image:

[image]

But, this isn't the case here. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Structure of NO2 compound?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9448/structure-of-no2-compound)

Comment: But, @NilayGhosh that post asks about whether the single electron will stay on Nitrogen or on Oxygen. Whereas I want some insight on how a single electron stays on Nitrogen.

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is an odd number of electrons, they have to be distributed as best as they can, preferably so that all elements get as close to 8 as possible (but not more).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I was saying that why did N **donated** only one electron (I've read that electrons are always donated in pair) to O, instead N could also make a bond with O, gaining a co-valency of four.

Comment: Where ever you read that electrons are donated in pairs, you either have missed some context, or the book is grossly oversimplifying, or even completely wrong. $\ce{NO2}$ is an **odd** electron species, or a radical. It is also a very complicated bonding situation. The way you are trying to rationalise is insufficient for it. If there were a double bond between oxygen and nitrogen, then one of the elements would exceed the 8 valence electrons, which is not possible for these elements. Please [edit] your question with all the conceptual issues you have to make it clearer.